# I run into this error when i try to deploy on Linea testnet using hardhat: Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I run into this error when i try to deploy on Linea testnet using hardhat:

> Invalid value {"url":"https://linea-goerli.infura.io/v3/32fc859dcfd14d5c80d0f32e5a9bd450","account":["1324236175621babb9e638a8e8820632e7ae075d1aedbed1fd12cb88701b10d5"],"chainId":"59140"} for HardhatConfig.networks.linea - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkConfig.

The hardhat.config.js file

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("dotenv").config()
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */

const LINEA_RPC_URL = process.env.LINEA_RPC_URL
const LINEA_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.LINEA_PRIVATE_KEY

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        linea: {
            url: LINEA_RPC_URL,
            account: [LINEA_PRIVATE_KEY],
            chainId: "59140",
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.18",
}
```

it's supposed to deploy to the linea testnet but it just returns this error instead.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=Expected+a+value+of+type+HttpNetworkConfig.+site:stackoverflow.com).